# How to read UDP data from a given port with python in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, powershell

On Windows 10 I want to read data from UDP port 9001. I have created the following script which does not give any output (python 3.10.9):

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("", 9001))
    
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recv(1024)
    print(f"received message: {data.decode()} from {addr}")
```

I checked that a device is sending UDP data on port 9001 using **wireshark**. But the above code just "runs" on powershell without any output (and without any errors).

Any ideas how to fix this?

I found [this page](https://cloudbrothers.info/en/test-udp-connection-powershell/) with a **powershell** script that is supposed to listen to a UDP port. So I tried this and created a file `Start-UDPServer.ps1` with the content as described in that page as follows:

```
function Start-UDPServer {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # Parameter help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        $Port = 10000
    )
    
    # Create a endpoint that represents the remote host from which the data was sent.
    $RemoteComputer = New-Object System.Net.IPEndPoint([System.Net.IPAddress]::Any, 0)
    Write-Host "Server is waiting for connections - $($UdpObject.Client.LocalEndPoint)"
    Write-Host "Stop with CRTL + C"

    # Loop de Loop
    do {
        # Create a UDP listender on Port $Port
        $UdpObject = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient($Port)
        # Return the UDP datagram that was sent by the remote host
        $ReceiveBytes = $UdpObject.Receive([ref]$RemoteComputer)
        # Close UDP connection
        $UdpObject.Close()
        # Convert received UDP datagram from Bytes to String
        $ASCIIEncoding = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
        [string]$ReturnString = $ASCIIEncoding.GetString($ReceiveBytes)

        # Output information
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            LocalDateTime = $(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d %T")
            SourceIP      = $RemoteComputer.address.ToString()
            SourcePort    = $RemoteComputer.Port.ToString()
            Payload       = $ReturnString
        }
    } while (1)
}
```

and started it in an **Powershell** terminal (as admin) as

```
.\Start-UDPServer.ps1 -Port 9001
```

and it returned to the Powershell immediately without ANY output (or error message). Maybe windows is broken?

If there is a solution to finally listen to UDP port 9001, I still strongly prefer a **python** solution!

Comment: Have you checked if the Firewall on the system is blocking the traffic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, your posted Python code should have given you an error when run if it was receiving any data, so that suggests that the data was not getting to the process at all.

I'd recommend checking your Windows Firewall settings for that port, and any other host-based firewalls you might be running.

But also, the `recv()` method does not return a tuple. `recvfrom()` does, so the following code works:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("", 9001))
    
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print(f"received message: {data.decode()} from {addr}")
```

A tangential note: the Powershell script does not actually start a UDP server, it just creates a function to do so. So you need to add a line `Start-UDPServer -Port 9001` at the end to call the function if you want it to actually listen for datagrams.

Comment: Actually part of the solution is to use "0.0.0.0" for the IP. And your code should not work as I cannot decode a tuple. `data = sock.recv(1024)` does work.

Comment: `data = sock.recv(1024)` works, as does `data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)`. What does not work is `data, addr = sock.recv(1024)` which is what is in the question above. If you want the address of the sending party then you need to use `recvfrom` instead of `recv`.
The `""` for the address  part of the passed tuple to `bind` is translated to `INADDR_ANY` for the socket address family used and binds to all addresses.